# How many minor edits in a day is too much?

Tags: discussion, editing

Related:
[Policy regarding mass minor edits](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/840/26335)
<sub>The post [Why do we make small edits to very old posts?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/645/26335) seems really more about age of post than "size" of the edit. Including just for completeness.</sub>

I noticed the following posts with edits by the same user in a very small time span (approximately 2 hours).

- [Mating with B+N+handicap](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39623/26335)
- [Who decides to name an opening?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39621/26335)
- [Why struggle for a single pawn?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/30122/26335)
- [Is attacking the kingside with White when Black kind-of plays the King Indian's defense setup a valid gameplan?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39466/26335)
- [What's the average total time for a game of bullet chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39194/26335)
- [What is the idea behind the Sicilian Flohr Variation?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39218/26335)
- [Puzzle: Forced game end in at most two halfmoves](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39633/26335)
- [Can a player in check win, by checkmating the opponent, while not getting themselves out of check?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39499/26335)
- https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/39607/26335

**Are proposed minor edits such as the following worthwhile to send to the Review Queue?**

Solely [adding backticks](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/39607/26335) to chess move notations?

Changing "any other organization" to "another organization"?
[image: Changing "any other organization" to "another organization"?]

One word edits that don't seem to change the meaning:
[image: Edit showing one word correction that doesn't change the English meaning]

I won't speculate whether a user is trying to just get +2 internet points.

Is this considered too many mass minor edits on Chess.SE? (especially considering these are proposed edits and require reviewers)

Comment: IMHO it's a bit dumb to be complaining that people are being too helpful. Is the burden of approving these minor edits really so much? Hopefully soon they will have enough points that they don't require reviewing.

Comment: Different SE sites have different views on this I guess...hence my question for Chess.SE.

Comment: @SteveBennett some of these edits are not improvements (e.g., changing "of" to "behind", the edit that solely added backticks).  I think your comment is reasonable (for minor edits but clear improvements) until you start defending those kind of edits (no real improvement).

Comment: The minor edits were made by me (you probably alr know this). I am only making these small "improvements" only after realising that many others do the same. And i sorta do agree with @SteveBennett